# Como dividir uma aplicação node em arquivos

Tags: javascript

Como importar o arquivos model/connection.js para model/tables.js

model/connection.js

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize('caoperdido', 'root', '', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql'
});

sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
  console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
}).catch(err => {
  console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
});
```

model/tables.js

```
const User = sequelize.define('user', {
    // attributes
    firstName: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    lastName: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING
      // allowNull defaults to true
    }
  });
  
  User.sync({ force: true }).then(() => {
    return User.create({
      firstName: 'Diovane',
      lastName: 'Maia'
    });
  });
```

Comment: Onde estão as imagens `menino.png` e `menina.png` no seu computador? Como você não está dando um caminho relativo para essas imagens, o navegador irá procurar por elas na raiz do seu computador/servidor. Se as imagens estão na mesma pasta do seu html, você poderia acessa-las como o caminho `./menino.png`. Se estiverem dentro de um diretório, seria algo como `./imgs/menino.png`. Se estiverem em um diretório acima do html, `../menino.png`. Localize as imagens e dê use o caminho apropriado para acessa-las.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É um erro de digitação na linha:

```
hres.appendClild(img)
```

O metodo `appendClild` não existe o correto seria:

```
hres.appendChild(img)
```